# Simple Graph Transformation Question $\rightarrow$ $1/f(x)$

Tags: graphing-functions, transformation

for the graph:
[image]

such that the function is : $ y = \frac{a+x}{b+cx} $ where a = -2, b = 1 and c = 1/2

how do you sketch the graph of $ y = |\frac{b+cx}{a+x}| $  ??

i got that the VA of the new graph is "$+2$" and the root of the new graph is "$-2$", but then the answer says that the horizontal asymptote is "$\frac{1}{2}$" which i don't really understand..

Could anyone explain to me what to happen, if i am to transform a graph from $f(x)$ to $\frac{1}{f(x)}$.

i only know that the roots of $f(x)$ will become VA value of $1/f(x)$ and VA values of $f(x)$ becomes the zeros of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$

and that if $f(x) \gt 0$ , then $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ $\gt 0$ such that $f(x) \to 0 \implies \frac{1}{f(x)} \to \infty$ and $f(x) \to \infty \implies \frac{1}{f(x)} \to  0$.

Comment: You're most of the way there already. To find horizontal asymptotes, just consider what happens when $x \to \pm \infty$

Comment: The absolute value is a little trickier to deal with. I like to think about it graphically by first drawing the input function and then reflecting just the parts of the graph that happen to go below the x-axis to above the x-axis.

Comment: the answer says that the y-intercept and the HA is 1/2 which is pretty odd.. because i try to make x = 0 for the new function.. and I got 2 as my answer which contradicts the answer..i'm not sure if i had done it wrong or the answer was just wrong

Comment: You may find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/263930/48586) useful

Comment: The horizontal asymptote is not what happens when x=0 (that's just the y-intercept) but what happens as x grows without bound in both directions. Take $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{2}x}{-2+x}$: it is $\frac{1}{2}$ for both positive and negative infinity, and you can verify the derivative goes to 0 in both directions so it is an asymptote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function
$$f(x) = \frac{x-2}{\frac{x}{2} + 1}$$
and you want to sketch $y = \frac{1}{f(x)}$.

The $y$-intercept of the graph $y = f(x)$ is given by $f(0)$ (let this be $y_0$). The $y$-intercept of the graph $y = \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is given by $\frac{1}{f(0)}$, which is the reciprocal of $y_0$.

Similarly, the old horizontal asymptote, $y = \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 2$, will become $y = \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)} = \frac{1}{2}$, since $f(x)$ is being replaced by $\frac{1}{f(x)}$.

In general, the $y$ values of $y = f(x)$ will be the reciprocals of $y = \frac{1}{f(x)}$, i.e.,

$$y_{\text{new}} = \frac{1}{y_{\text{old}}}.$$

To then sketch the absolute value of this function, simply reflect any part below the $x$-axis above it, so there are no negative $y$ values for any $x$.

Pictures speak a thousand words...

Note that for each $x$ value, the $y$ values are reciprocals:
[image: Reciprocal graph]

Reflecting the part below the $x$-axis:
[image: Absolute value graph]

Also, technically $f$ is not defined at $x = -2$, so neither should $\frac{1}{f}$ or $\left | \frac{1}{f} \right |$, i.e., there are holes at $x=-2$ on the blue graphs.